# Passing object between two Override methods

Tags: java, android

Some basic stuff:

I have two override methods in java:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
Car car = new Car();
}
```

im creating an object inside
and want to call this object in second @Override

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        car.drive();
    }
```

How can i pass this object between this two methods ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare the variable outside the `onCreate` and initialize it inside the `onCreate`.

```
Car car = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    car = new Car();
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (car != null) {
        car.drive();
    }
}
```